# Position of opening parenthesis

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to make a function that passed a string that would be a mathematical expression and a parenthesis position, return the position of the opening parenthesis of the position that I passed as a parameter.

example:

```
myfunction('(7 * 3) +1', 4)
```

should return `0` because the parentheses that enclose position 4 open at position 0.

I even tried to do, but it only works with some expressions depending on the position and I pass.

I've tried

```
def pos_open_parent(exp, pos_closed):

        temp_exp = exp[:pos_closed]
        count_open = 0
        count_closed = 1

        i = len(temp_exp) -1
        while count_open != count_closed:
                if temp_exp[i] == '(':
                        count_open += 1
                elif temp_exp[i] == ')':
                        count_closed += 1
                i -= 1
        return i + 1
```

Comment: Can you share what have you tried so far with us?

Comment: `return = 0` is something you can't do, because `return` is a reserved word.

Comment: @tobias_k is the position of the matching opening parenthesis.

Comment: Take a look at the methods that strings have, like rfind etc. If those aren't good enough for you, then you can start playing with the re module, aka `import re`

Comment: @Carpetsmoker its only a example. i know this

Comment: @user3448245 Yes, I misread your question. Now I see that you want it to return `o` for that input. Have you tried counting opening/closing parens?

Comment: Your functions seems to work pretty well, you just have to add a check for when there is no matching opening parentheses, use a try/except or check whether i < 0. Is there an example for which it does not work?

Comment: See my answer. It has a balance-check (note: you should catch exception in pop() since the string could be malformed.

Comment: @user3448245 Just curious, did the below answers help you? If so, it would be nice if you'd accept the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 2):

Your code seems to work quite well, actually, you just have to consider the case where there is no matching opening parentheses, otherwise it will throw an exception.

As a slight variation of your algorithm, I'd suggest scanning the expression backwards, counting the number of opening parenthesis you still need, and returning the index as soon as that number reaches zero.

```
def pos_open_parens(exp, pos):
    count = 1                           # one open parens to find
    for i in range(pos, -1, -1):
        if exp[i] == ')': count += 1    # now we need one more...
        if exp[i] == '(': count -= 1    # found one!
        if count == 0: return i         # found all the parens we need
    return None                         # no matching open parens -> None
```

For `'(7*(1+4)-3)+1'` and positions `2`, `4`, `9`, and `11`, this returns `0`, `3`, `0`, and `None`, i.e. if no opening parenthesis is found (or not enough to match closing parentheses) it will return `None`.

Note that this *could* mean that there are unbalanced parentheses in the expression, but it could also be perfectly okay, as in my last example. To check for unbalanced parentheses, you could use a similar algorithm, scanning the *entire* string and checking whether the count is balanced.

Comment: Love the count approach. It doesn't generalize if we mix different type of brackets though. '[(5+4)+ 3] * 5'. (yes I know, that's not what op is asking for, just had this issue with a challenge lately :))

Comment: You probably want to raise an error (or return a sentinel value) if you reach the start of the string without `count` reaching zero. That can also be a useful thing to do if you try to solve @SamyArous's further issue by having multiple kinds of brackets you're counting (use separate counts for each type, return if they're all zero, raise an exception if any ever go negative).

Comment: @Blckknght I thought of `None` as such a value for 'nothing found', see my last example. Raising an exception would be possible, too. It's a matter of taste, I guess. (In fact, if it threw an exception, it would the just the same as what OP already has!)

Comment: @tobias_k: Ah, I see. I hadn't considered the sentinel approach at first (I edited it in to my comment). Since there are many well formed expression strings that don't have parentheses around everything, it probably does make sense to return `None` or `-1` or something like that rather than raising an exception, though you might want to raise if the count is greater than one (which would indicate unbalanced parentheses). And I'd still suggest an explicit `return None` statement rather than using the implicit return from falling off the end of the function.

Comment: @Blckknght Ah, now I see. However, it will be difficult to differentiate the case where there is no open parens needed, like in my last example, and cases where there should be one. To check whether the expression is valid, you'd have to scan the entire string, including what's right of the initial position (e.g. for `3+4), 2`). Maybe that should go into a separate method.

Comment: @Blckknght using 3 different counters is not enough, take this example: **{(})**, you will not detect any problem if you use counters, yet it is an invalid expression. Using a last_element variable fails too for this expression: **{({()){}}}**. The only approach I could find was using a stack. Might be something else I'm overseeing though

Answer (score 1):

This script assumes your expr string is parenthesis-balanced.

Explanation:

1. if expr[par] is not a closing parenthesis, the input is wrong (you have to specify the closing parenthesis as in your example).
2. note i return strings on error. this algorithm is just illustrative. return what you want, or raise exceptions.
3. the algorithm pushes every position of '(' it finds, and pops when finds a matching ')'. if the current position of the current ')' if the one you want, the popped '(' will be in the position you want, because the push and pop control parenthesis-balancing.

Code:

```
def find_matching_openin_par(expr, par):
    if expr[par] != ')':
        return "the specified pos is not a closing paren."
    else:
        opens = []
        for index, ch_ in enumerate(expr):
            if ch_ == '(':
                opens.append(index)
                #add a new opening paren. to the list
            elif ch_ == ')':
                #get the last added position of a "(" parenthesis.
                pos = opens.pop() #it may throw an exception if the string is unbalanced!
                if index == par:
                    #we keep that position, since all previously matched parenthesis were popped.
                    return pos
        return "not found. malformed string"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is easy to solve assuming the expression is always valid.

- initialize a stack
- traverse the string
- if current char is an opening parenthesis, push its position to the
  stack
- if current char is a closing parenthesis, pop one element from the
  stack
- if you reach the wanted position and the stack is empty return -1
- else return the last element

Here's an implementation of the following:

```
def yourfunction(first_arg, second_arg):
    stack = []
    for i, c in enumerate(first_arg):
        if i == second_arg:
            return -1 if len(stack) == 0 else stack.pop()
        if c == '(':
            stack.append(i)
        elif c == ')':
            if len(stack) > 0:  
                stack.pop()
            else:
                raise ValueError('Mathematical expression is invalid. Check your parenthesis')

print yourfunction('(7*3)+1', 4)
0
print yourfunction('((7)*3)+1', 6)
0
print yourfunction('((7)*(3)+1', 7)
5
```

Answer (score 0):

This requires parsing only up to the position you provided. It does not attempt to enforce valid expressions. You should do that separately.

Something you didn't specify is for positions that are outside of any parentheses. I implemented it to return `-1` for any positions that are not contained in parentheses.

## Copy-Paste Code

```
def myfunction(expression, position):
    open_positions = list()
    for i, c in enumerate(expression):
        if c == '(':
            # found a new open parens. everything after this points to here
            # until a new one is opened or this one is closed
            open_positions.append(i)
        if i == position:
            # this is the position we are looking for
            # return the current open parentheses position (or -1 if no parens)
            try:
                return open_positions[-1]
            except IndexError:
                return -1
        if c == ')':
            # closed a set of parentheses so nothing else can be inside
            # remove the current open parentheses
            open_positions.pop()  # finished parens before getting to position

expression          = '(1*((2+3)*4))+5'
visual_confirmation = '012345678901234'
for i in range(len(expression)):
    open_position = myfunction(expression, i)
    print 'open parens for position {} at {}'.format(i, open_position)
```

## Output

```
open parens for position 0 at 0
open parens for position 1 at 0
open parens for position 2 at 0
open parens for position 3 at 3
open parens for position 4 at 4
open parens for position 5 at 4
open parens for position 6 at 4
open parens for position 7 at 4
open parens for position 8 at 4
open parens for position 9 at 3
open parens for position 10 at 3
open parens for position 11 at 3
open parens for position 12 at 0
open parens for position 13 at -1
open parens for position 14 at -1
```